# Error Searching Row for Date and returning column letter

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

Trying to search a specific row for a date. Then return that column letter after converting it from the column number. Once the column letter is returned, gathering and transferring of data to sheet2 is expected. Am currently getting a type mismatch 13. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Color()

Dim CountColor As Long
Dim CountBlack As Long
Dim CountWhite As Long
Dim TextWhite As String
Dim TextBlack As String
Dim TextRed As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
Dim ColumnLetter As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dateini = 1 / 22 / 2021

ColumnNumber = ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Find(What:=1 / 22 / 2021, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
    
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)


For Each cell In Range("A1:Z1")

If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

    CountColor = CountColor + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1").Value = CountColor
    TextRed = cell.Offset(0, -Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & CountColor).Value = TextRed
    
ElseIf cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then

    CountBlack = CountBlack + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2").Value = CountBlack
    TextBlack = cell.Offset(0, -Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & CountBlack).Value = TextBlack
    
ElseIf cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then

    CountWhite = CountWhite + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E3").Value = CountWhite
    TextWhite = cell.Offset(0, -Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J" & CountWhite).Value = TextWhite

End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: There a few errors but first which row do you want to search because `ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Find(`™is searching a column not a row.

Comment: sorry, for instance wanting to search through Row 1 which is a row of dates. was only using column B to narrow the scope of the code to B1 essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code the compiler will tell you that `LastRow` and `Dateini` are not defined.
2. `Dateini = 1 / 22 / 2021` assigns a numerical value of  2.24911160091764E-05 which as a Date is `1899-12-30`. Use `Dateini = Format("2021-01-22","yyyy-mm-dd")` and the date is unambiguous.
3. `Dim ColumnLetter As Integer` should be `As String`
4. `ColumnNumber = .Find(...).Column` will throw an error if the search value is not found. Assign the `.Find()` to a range and then test for `NOT nothing` before assigning `ColumnNumber = rng.Column`
5. `Find(What:=1 / 22 / 2021, After:=ActiveCell` should be`Find(What:=Dateini,` and it will error if the Active cell is not in the search range.
6. You need to explain what this line does `cell.Offset(0,-Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))` as it looks wrong with `-` sign and `Abs()`.
7. Note also `Color` is a Property of some Objects and therefore not a good choice of name for a Macro. Use something like `ColorMacro`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColorMacro()

    Dim CountWhite As Long, CountBlack As Long, CountColor As Long
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
    Dim ColumnLetter As String ' was Integer
    
    Dim Dateini As Date
    Dateini = DateValue("2021-01-01") '  1 / 22 / 2021
    
    Dim rngFound As Range, cell As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' or Thisworkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set rngFound = ws1.Rows(1).Find(What:=Dateini, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    ' check if date found
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find " & Format(Dateini, "yyyy-mm-dd"), vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print Format(Dateini, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
        & " found in " & rngFound.Address(1, 1, xlA1, True)
    End If

    ColumnNumber = rngFound.Column
    ColumnLetter = Split(rngFound.Address, "$")(1)
    
    For Each cell In ws1.Range("A1:Z1")
    
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then       
            CountColor = CountColor + 1
            ws2.Range("F" & CountColor).Value = cell.Offset(0, Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))         
        ElseIf cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            CountBlack = CountBlack + 1
            ws2.Range("G" & CountBlack).Value = cell.Offset(0, Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))    
        ElseIf cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            CountWhite = CountWhite + 1
            ws2.Range("J" & CountWhite).Value = cell.Offset(0, Abs(ColumnNumber - 1))
        End If

    Next cell

    ' counts
    With ws2
        .Range("F:F,G:G,J:J").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Range("E1").Value = CountColor
        .Range("E2").Value = CountBlack
        .Range("E3").Value = CountWhite
    End With
    MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Really appreciate it!